# Html purifier removes image style no matter the configuration, how do I allow it?

Tags: styles, sanitization, htmlpurifier

I'm using https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier package for Laravel and I have encountered an issue that no matter my configuration, style attribute is always removed from the input.
Here's my configuration

```
        'HTML.Allowed'  => 'font[color|style],h1[class|style],h2[class|style],h3[class|style],h4[class|style],h5[class|style],div[class|style],b,strong,i,em,a[href|title|class|style],ul,ol,li,p[style|class],br,span[style|class],img[style|width|height|alt|src|class],table[style|class],tbody[style|class],thead[style|class],tr[style|class],td[style|class],th[style|class]',
        'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align,width',
```

Here's my input:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.deve/storage/1278/5f97ed8127418_5f8efd4d61487_image.png" class="img h-auto" style="width: 25%;" alt="" title="" role="">
```

And this is what I get after applying purifier's "clean"

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.deve/storage/1278/5f97ed8127418_5f8efd4d61487_image.png" class="img h-auto" alt="">
```

Is my config wrong? I've been stuck with this issue for a few hours now, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this post https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier/issues/68 I finally managed to get it working. In config just needed to add 'CSS.MaxImgLength' => null, under 'CSS.AllowedProperties'=> '...'